# What is the Application Name for Nopcommerce 4.60 no source code

Tags: asp.net-core, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.90, nopcommerce-4.0, nopcommerce-4.2

I'm using no source code in nopcommerce 4.60. I'm trying to run this code in my root folder but I don't know what my ApplicationName is {yourApplicationName}.

```
dotnet {yourApplicationName}.dll
```

Comment: [Install nopCommerce - Without Source Code](https://docs.nopcommerce.com/en/installation-and-upgrading/installing-nopcommerce/installing-on-windows.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't change your nopCommerce application's DLL name until you modify the entire nopCommerce solution source code from Nop.Web to {YourApplication Name}.
It'll always remain the name as per nop library project.